# How to remove horizontal grid line in Google Column Chart?

Tags: google-visualization

How can I remove the horizontal grid line in my google column chart?
I tried some of the solutions but can't still remove it. Thanks.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
        ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
        ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
        ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
        ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
        ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
        ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(
        data,
        {
            title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Years", minorGridlines: { color: 'red' } }
        }
    );
}​
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The horizontal grid lines are controlled by the vAxis.gridlines option.  Set the vAxis.gridlines.color option to "transparent" to make them disappear:

```
vAxis: {
    gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks asgallant. It worked. But I don't get it why the vAxis option should used to make it transparent. I keep on using the hAxis option a while ago but it didn't work.

Comment: The API links the horizontal gridlines with the vAxis labels (every label has a major gridline, and the way it is set up, you actually set a count of gridlines to determine how many labels you will get).  Also, you can have two y-axes in most charts, each with its own set of gridlines, which you may want to control separately, so it becomes necessary to put control under the vAxis option.

Comment: You are a genius, sir!

Answer (score 2):

Something else worth trying for your chart options (if you don't want the lines there at all):

```
var options = {
    ...
    vAxis : {
        gridlines : {
            count : 0
        }
    }
};
```